# Add Keybinding to ./program

Tags: vim, cmake

I recently dumped all ide's and decided to program solely with vim. So far it works good, but I have a minor annoyance. Everytime I want to run my recently compiled program, I have to write

```
:!./myProgramExecutable
```

I could do this in my .vimrc:

```
nmap <key> :!./myProgramExecutable<CR>
```

but that would only work for executables of that name. Is there a way to generalize this command for my current project in CMakeLists.txt for example? (or another way to find the correct name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the program name can be derived from the current buffer's path and/or name, you can use `:help filename-modifiers` in the command execution.

However, if it's okay for you to specify the program name *once*, a neat trick is that `:!!` repeats the *last* `:!` command with the same arguments. If you bind that to a key, you have a quick way to re-execute it.

Oh, and if you're working with Makefiles or similar, why not create a target (always with the same name) that executes the program; you can then do that from Vim via `:make run`, for instance.

Comment: Thanks for the :!! tip, it works fine, the problem is if I use another command too, but that is another concern.